# How to efficiently insert/merge into thrust::device_vector?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I'd like to merge several `device_vectors` into one, like so:

```
thrust::device_vector<int>         allinput = input0;
allinput.insert(allinput.end(),input1.begin(),input1.end());
allinput.insert(allinput.end(),input2.begin(),input2.end());
allinput.insert(allinput.end(),input3.begin(),input3.end());
```

But obviously I'd like to do it efficiently. I'm working with key `device_vectors` and value `device_vectors` and I'd like to do this for both.

Which is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Another problem I have is that I only know how many key & value `device_vectors` I will have until runtime. Is there a way of making a `device_vector<device_vector>` or to access several vectors by pointer somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "efficient".

Comment: @talonmies I meant time-efficiently. I'd like to do it in parallel. Normally, I'd use a vector of pointers to loop over all the inputs, but that isn't the sense of using thrust, afaik.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reserve (size_type n)` before insert in order to speed up subsequent insertions:

```
thrust::device_vector<int>         allinput = input0;

allinput.reserve(input1.size()+input2.size()+input3.size());

allinput.insert(allinput.end(),input1.begin(),input1.end());
allinput.insert(allinput.end(),input2.begin(),input2.end());
allinput.insert(allinput.end(),input3.begin(),input3.end());
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll implement that. Do you have any idea how I could parallelize this process?